# Properly select actual non-alphanumeric characters in MySQL column

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a strange issue with my MySQL REGEXP SELECT query, I'm trying to select rows which contain non-alphanumeric characters. I've tried multiple things and it will match Cyrillic characters, but it does not consider apostrophes and spaces to be non-alphanumeric. Here are the queries I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` REGEXP '^[^[:alnum:]]+$' LIMIT 0,10;

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` REGEXP '^[^a-z0-9]+$' LIMIT 0,10;
```

They both return nothing at all now because I've replaced all of the Cyrillic characters, except for spaces and apostrophes. I feel as though I must be doing something incorrectly, because it seems so illogical that MySQL would consider a space and apostrophe to be alphanumeric.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name REGEXP "[^a-z0-9]+" LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: That actually works, I think perhaps I mixed up the initial ^ and $ for meaning it would span all but I was only scanning the first and last characters. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there anyway to show the offending characters too? I've some Russian strings here and I would like to replace those. Of course I am using a regex with Russian characters instead of alphanumeric, and it works to find which rows have offending characters, but cannot tell which ones are since, you know, dealing with different languages sometimes there are characters that look exactly the same despite not being the same (for example A and А look the same, but the first one is a Latin A and the second a Cyrillic one, so they are different chars).